# Any batch processing system in the cloud?

Tags: amazon-web-services, batch-file, amazon-ec2, cloud, batch-processing

I have a PHP-based website that executes a binary (C++ standalone compiled code). Right now I have this system in an Amazon EC2 machine, so that I am able to freely execute this binary.

What I need is a service in the cloud to which I could send the binary such a batch processing system. In this way, I would be charged only by the execution time of the binary and, moreover, I could instantly scale out my website (without the latency of starting new machines each time I want to execute the binary).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about having a message queue with a worker. Unfortunately there are no options in ec2 which will allow you to run the worker exactly as you want to.

With AWS, the closest you will get is to set up an auto scaling group based on an SQS queue. However, if no instances are running, an instance will still take time to spin up.

Some more information can be found here: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/Amazon-SQS/1464

Comment: I don't have to stick to Amazon, so is it possible to find the service I described somewhere else?

Comment: Many services are based around virtual machines which take time to spin up and down. Some platform as a service operators may be able to do more what you are expecting, but generally you are limited to using supported languages and may be restricted from doing certain types of processing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product - Batchly which does batch processing on the cloud. For more information, please check http://www.batchly.net/